# What features won't I get with a Magic Mouse under Windows XP and 7?

Tags: windows, mouse

I like the magic mouse for the two-finger scroll and other features under Snow Leopard.  Which of those features will not work under Windows XP and 7.  I have XP on a home machine and 7 at work, so I care about both.

Comment: I would be very surprised if it didn't support two finger scrolling. I have no experience with the Magic Mouse, but the two finger scrolling gesture works on Windows 7 with the Magic Trackpad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get scroll (and maybe a few others) by using Apple's Boot Camp drivers. Article [here](http://uneasysilence.com/archive/2009/11/14588/). All the links to the drivers seem to be gone, so you may have to extract them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Magic Mouse on my laptop, and dual boot between OS X and Windows 7.

The basic mouse functionality works well, but the scrolling does not work at all (neither vertical or horizontal), and the gestures do not work either, as all of these functions are done by software and don't use the standard MouseWheel commands that windows expects.

I set it up a long time ago so my memory has faded, but I think you may also have to install the some apple mouse driver package from the Snow Leopard Boot Camp DVD too, but hopefully I'm wrong and you don't need this.